# Powershell Scripting get-childitem all site

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am documenting all the sites and binding related to the site from the IIS.
Unfortunately, exclusion does not work.

```
Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites\domain -Name | Where {$_.Name -notlike "*\bin\*"}
```

I have a problem with subdirectories as well, I don't want them to show up under the folder

test

test\test

test23

test21

Comment: Hmmm ... 'never worked with the `IIS:` provider but your regex pattern should look something like this I think: `'.*\\bin\\.*'`.

Comment: @Olaf the `-like` operator supports wildcards, not regex

Comment: When you use `-Name` with `Get-ChildItem`, it usually only returns bare strings. try changing the filter to: `Where {$_ -notlike '*\bin\*'}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  .... ooops, you're right.  Sorry. So, forget about my comment.  ;-)